# Dynamic variables for structure

Tags: c

I have a structure:

```
struct options {
    char *type;
    char *action;
} params;
```

'type' and 'action' arrive from user input, and this is required parameters.
But, i want to geting optional parameters and record it to struct.
How can i do this? Is this possible?

Comment: Assign a special value if they're unassigned or create several different `struct`ures with different fields.  Obviously, option 2 is not ideal.

Comment: Solutions for optional data could differ wildly between the two different languages C and C++. So please pick *one*, which one are you really programming in?

Comment: For strings a common way to handle optional data is to simply have variables that are `NULL` if there's no data.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude programmer dude, I am begginer in this branch. To many peoply said me C++ and C has a little differents

Comment: @ДмитрийКозырев So many people are very wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## C++ Way

Depending on the type(s) of the optional parameters, you might want to consider `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` with an appropriate template type (e.g., some sort of polymorphic base reference).

## C Way

This gets a little tricky, but there are some design options. In short, you're going to have to default the optional parameters to some common type (e.g., char-strings), and have a struct pairing them appropriately. For example,

```
typedef struct{
  char  param[32];
  char* val;
} ParameterPair;
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++17 you can use std::optional for this sort of thing.

```
#include <optional>

struct optional_params {
    int color;
    float frobication_level;
} params;

struct options {
    const char* type;
    const char* action;
    std::optional<optional_params> extra;
};

void useOptions(const options& opts) {
    // ...
    if (opts.extra.has_value()) {
        auto [color, frob_lvl] = opts.extra.value();
        // ...
    }
}

options opts = { "foo","bar", optional_params{1, 42.0} };
useOptions(opts);
```